# Calculate MAE, MSE and R2 metrics for a DNNRegressor model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics

I have a `DNNRegressor` model and I want to calculate some metrics to understand how well my model is predicting. How can I calculate the mean absolute error (MAE), mean squared error (MSE) and the R squared coefficient?

So far I only have the loss so can someone help me calculate MAE, MSE and R2?

```
# Imports 
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

import statsmodels.api as sm

COLUMNS = ['Prot', 'Gra', 'Cen', 'Sal', 'TVN', 'Velocidad_Prensa']
FEATURES = ['Prot', 'Gra', 'Cen', 'Sal', 'TVN']
LABEL = ['Velocidad_Prensa']

def get_input_fn(data_set, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
  return tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
      x=pd.DataFrame({k: data_set[k].values for k in FEATURES}),
      y=pd.Series(data_set[LABEL].values),
      num_epochs=num_epochs,
      shuffle=shuffle)

training_set = pd.read_csv("prensa train.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
test_set = pd.read_csv("prensa eval.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
training_set.head()

# Model

feature_cols = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in FEATURES]

regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols, 
                                          activation_fn = tf.nn.relu, hidden_units=[200, 100, 50, 25, 12])

# Reset the index of training
training_set.reset_index(drop = True, inplace =True)
def input_fn(data_set, pred = False):
    
    if pred == False:
        
        feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values) for k in FEATURES}
        labels = tf.constant(data_set[LABEL].values)
        
        return feature_cols, labels

    if pred == True:
        feature_cols = {k: tf.constant(data_set[k].values) for k in FEATURES}
        
        return feature_cols

# Deep Neural Network Regressor with the training set which contain the data split by train test split
regressor.train(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(training_set), steps=2000)

# Evaluation on the test set created by train_test_split
ev = regressor.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test_set), steps=1)

# Display the score on the testing set
loss_score1 = ev["loss"]
print("Final Loss on the testing set: {0:f}".format(loss_score1))

def input_fn(features, batch_size=256):
  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(features)).batch(batch_size)

features = ['Prot', 'Gra', 'Cen', 'Sal','TVN']
predict = {}

print("Ingresar características químicas de la materia prima")
for feature in features:
  valid = True
  while valid:
    val = input(feature + ": ")
    if not val.isdigit(): valid = False

  predict[feature] = [float(val)]


predictions = regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(predict))

for pred_dict in predictions:
    print(pred_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn.metrics` has dedicated scoring methods for each of the metrics you are asking for.

Just to the following:

```py
# Import metrics
from sklearn import metrics

# Make predictions
predictions = regressor.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(predict))

# Calculate MAE, MSE, R2
print('MAE:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true, predictions))
print('MSE:', metrics.mean_squared_error(y_true, predictions))
print('R2:', metrics.r2_score(y_true, predictions))
```

Comment: I saw that code, but i didn't split my data, I have 2 different files, So i dont know what to change the y_true. That code you sent me I had used that one already for a Linear Regression model i was doing but i cant figure out how to fit it to this DNNRegressor

Comment: Do you mean you do not have a `y_true` array? Could you post a sample of `predictions` and `y_true` if you have it?

Comment: Yes, i dont have a y_true array, The thing is that i made to files, one to train the model and the other to test the model.

Comment: Ingresar características químicas de la materia prima
Prot: 19.8
Gra: 6.5
Cen: 2.3
Sal: 0.8
TVN: 22.0
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/tmp2bo64kl_/model.ckpt-2000
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
{'predictions': array([2.093052], dtype=float32)}

Comment: When i run the model it asks me to insert some values once i put in the values it predicts me the value.

Comment: Ok, you do not have a `y_true` array. Do you have the real values for the testing data somewhere? I see your data is in Spanish. If you want, you can open up a chat and talk to me in Spanish.

Comment: I have the testing data in my pc. I am kinda new in this how can i open a chat up?

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231544/how-can-i-start-a-chat-with-a-particular-user) a post that explains how to do it.